# Getting the second to last working day

Tags: sas

I'm trying to get the second to last working day of any month , the holidays are not taken into account.

I've tried with that code but I got stuck especially with the `intnx`, which is giving me the last day...

```
data tata;
test=today();
put test=;
run;

data toto;
set tata;
lastDay=intnx('month',"test"d,0,'E');
format lastDay ddmmyy10.;
run;
```

I'm welcoming any tips that will unlock me.

Comment: guys !!!! I've got awarded 130 points !!!! Wahhhh !!! (not related but extreme joy !!!!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution works well

```
data toto;
2ndlastDay=intnx('weekday',intnx('month',date(),0,'E'),-1);
format lastDay ddmmyy10.;
run;
```